# Зависает превью в SurfaceView

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, моя задача - просто показывать в `SurfaceView` картинку с фронтальной камеры. Для этого использвую вот такой код, закинутый в основной класс:

```
//TESTCAM
new Thread(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {

 SurfaceView SurfaceView = (SurfaceView) mLockView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
 SurfaceHolder Holder = SurfaceView.getHolder();
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  Holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

 Camera Cam = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);

 try {

  Cam.setPreviewDisplay(Holder);
  Cam.startPreview();
 } 
 catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}               
}).start();
//TESTCAMSTOP
```

Проблема в том, что все выводится, но через некоторое время (всегда по разному) картинка просто зависает, бывает отвисает, бывает приложение падает. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Превью камеры должно работать в главном потоке. Убери Thread (это лишнее).

Следуй гайду из этой статьи - пункт Creating a preview class http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: Помогла вот эта статья - http://habrahabr.ru/post/112272/